# Why is PowerPoint 2010 Crashing While Editing Charts or Graphs?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I have several users who all experience the same crashing of PowerPoint 2010 when they edit charts or graphs.

The files they are editing are pptx and they are all using the 64 bit version or Office. The 32 bit version seems to work fine.

Is this a widespread issue with 64 bit Office installations? Has anyone found a solution besides using the 32 bit version?

Comment: Please define "crashing". Any error message you can share with us?

Comment: Check event logs as well  We need more info to help

Answer (score 0):

Think we may have figured this one out here, it appears that the charts are 2003 format, when the charts are converted they no longer cause PPT to freeze up. Thanks anyways!